# Thunderbird Add-on "Lightning": What is the difference between "Event" and "Task"?

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, tasks, events, lightning

If creating some date:

**When should I use `Event` instead of `Task` and the other way around?**

I saw that `Task` is also supporting `start time` and `due time`. Why does that make sense? When do I use which of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not unique to Lightning. Events and Tasks are common elements of any calendaring system.

The basic difference is that an Event requires attendance and therefore is a blocked off and unavailable period of time, while a Task is a point in time by which something must be completed/turned in/delivered/etc.

How you use these is up to you, and so different calendaring systems generally try to give you various options they believe will enable you to use them the way you want.

Lightning-specific discussion:http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=2564435
Clear description of the general concept of Events vs Tasks: https://www.lessannoyingcrm.com/help/topic/Calendars/68/What+is+the+difference+between+an+event+and+a+task%3F